# Spring Boot Routing

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a requirement to define a Spring Boot Route that looks like below:

**api/customers/{CustomerID}/Orders/{OrderID}**

Here both {CustomerID} and {OrderID} are numeric(int) values. For example see the below route:

http://localhost/api/customers/1234/Orders/5678

How do I accomplish this in SpringBoot using annotations?

Comment: do you any idea about `@RestController`, `@RequestMapping`?

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you need to read the Spring Boot [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-annotations) where you will find more information on how to make use of different types of annotations and design your endpoints.

What you need above is

- A controller with annotation `@RestController`
- Understand the difference between `@RequestParam` and `@PathParam`
- Understand the purpose of `RequestMapping`

Here is an example

```
@RestController
public class OrderController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{cid}/orders/{oid}", method = GET)
    public Order getOrder(@PathVariable int cid, @PathVariable int oid) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can see this useful [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping) on how and when to use `@RequestParam and @PathParam and @RequestMapping`. It's worth-mentioning that you can have as many controllers for example i.e. `CustomerController` and `OrderController` would be a good start and you can even annotate these controllers on top-level with `@RequestMapping("/customers") and @RequestMapping("/orders")`

Recent versions of Spring Boot also allows you to make use of the following annotations which are very handy

```
@GetMapping
@PostMapping
@PutMapping
@DeleteMapping
@PatchMapping
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@PathVariable` annotation to extract values and `@RequestMapping` to define the pattern: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping